How to remove double quote when importing csv file?
The data in csv file are quoted with double quote such as below:

Imported :

How to remove double quote which wrap data in the cell when importing csv file?

Simply set the double quote character in the "String Delimeter" field of the import box (its currently shown as  | in your screenshot)
